# dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIActivity

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

my iphone app runs in IOS 6.x but not on IOS 5. It crashes on IOS 5.x with the following message.
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIActivity

Comment: what is the deployment target of application?

Comment: The documentation should be your first stop for this kind of error.  -1 for no research.

Comment: my deployment target is version 5.0 and above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UIActivity class is available in iOS 6 and later .

[Apple docs class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivity_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[image]

Comment: ok i got it but how to incorporate it in ios 5.x

Comment: 1st thing why you are using that class

Comment: i am using sharekit and MBProgressHUD

Comment: Its solved now! The problem was in the sharekit. The new sharekit has resolved this issue.